# What is better to use: Action vs ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, action, actionlistener

Myself, I always use [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) as swing event-handler (e.g. button-click), and it is the most common listener I've seen in most swing applications.

However, Some Swing professionals here in stackoverflow often advise to use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) rather than [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html). What benefits I get from doing so?

Comment: Action can by shareable, blockable, settable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `Action` is preferred if you need to share functionality across components. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

> if you have two or more components that perform the same function, consider using an Action object to implement the function.

but also says

> An Action object is an action listener that provides not only action-event handling, but also centralized handling of the state of action-event-firing components such as tool bar buttons, menu items, common buttons, and text fields. The state that an action can handle includes text, icon, mnemonic, enabled, and selected status.

Comment: +1 for `Action`; [`FileMenu`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513) is a basic example. The benefit of doing it is not having to do it latter. :-)

Comment: What about creating a single action listener, and add the same reference to multiple swing components via `addActionListener()`? Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Actions have other additional goodies not found with ActionListeners including the ability to hold Icons, mnemonic keys, descriptions, and to hold any value-key you'd like.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ah I see +1. I like the last part more :) `and to hold any value-key you'd like`. +1 for Reimeus.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: It's also a good way to export functionality from a library, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14202720/230513).