# Should I use setAction or addActionListener in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a semi-theoretical problem involving Java and Swing. Swing components contain two options to respond to the user: `setAction` and `addActionListener`. These pertain to the `Action` and `ActionListener` objects, respectively.

My question is: which method, `setAction` or `addActionListener`, should I use? And how are they different from each other?

Comment: @lifus Thanks, closing. EDIT: This isn't actually a duplicate. Please don't cast your vote to close based on the fact that 2 votes exist.

Comment: `setAction(action)` will also call `addActionListener(action)` internally

Comment: @lifus That link relates to JSF...

Comment: Aha, Reimeus is correct. This is a different thing.

Comment: @meewoK We just went through this! :D It's not - this is the Swing framework.

Comment: You guys are killing me.

Comment: @meewoK did you read that link?

Comment: How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052225/what-is-better-to-use-action-vs-actionlistener Enjoy... this can easily be solved via googling!!!!

Comment: @meewoK better looks familiar too :P

Comment: @meewoK Hardly - it didn't come up in my SO query (or in the suggestions when I was writing the question). Nor did it come up on the first page and a half of my Google search.

Comment: @meewoK to be fair to the op, I search too (not very hard mind you) and didn't come up with anything either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personal preference is to use `Action` where possible (it doesn't always make sense to do so).  The main reasons are:

- Simplifies the code.  You don't end up with a `actionPerformed` method that is 100's of lines long with multiple if-else statements.  The `Action` contains a specific operation to a specific class.
- They are self contained (this is related to the previous point).  All the information need to configure the UI elements is self-contained to the `Action`, making it easier and quicker to setup, not to mention consistent ;)
- They are reusable, menus, buttons, key bindings, text fields.
- They are extendable.  You can create a basic concept of an action for a group and extended the base to provide the implementation requirements for individual actions (I do this a lot with key bindings)

IMHO

Comment: Thanks, accepting since it provides a bit of motivation (as opposed to docs only).

Answer (score 2):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

`An Action object is an action listener that provides not only action-event handling, but also centralized handling of the state of action-event-firing components such as tool bar buttons, menu items, common buttons, and text fields. The state that an action can handle includes text, icon, mnemonic, enabled, and selected status.`

Looking at the linked documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052225/what-is-better-to-use-action-vs-actionlistener), it seems one reason to use `Actions` could be trying to use the same Action on several objects

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I accepted the other because this is fairly similar to the answer of the duplicate posted above. Also, the other one provides a bit of real world motivation.